# How to log from PySpark app to HDFS using python logging library

Tags: python, hadoop, logging, pyspark, hdfs

How to log into HDFS using standard logging library. More specifically, I am using  *TimedRotatingFileHandler* like this:

```
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s — %(message)s")
LOG_FILE = 'hdfs://node01:8022/tmp/test/run_dev.log'
def get_file_handler():
   file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, when='midnight')
   file_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
   return file_handler
def get_logger(logger_name):
   logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
   if (logger.hasHandlers()): logger.handlers.clear() 
   logger.addHandler(get_file_handler())
   logger.propagate = False
   return logger
```

However it seems that I cannot pass fully qualified HDFS path as I was expecting. I am getting

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/bigdatamgr/hdfs:/node01:8022/tmp/test/run_dev.log'
```

Is there some way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: From PySpark you should be able to omit the base url and start from '/tmp' no?

Comment: From PySpark yes, but logging is not part of PySpark, its Python module.